# Error message misalignment in form fields

Tags: html, css, forms, pardot

I have a two-column form which looks great until the error messages show up on empty required fields.
[Colored to match error message to respective fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iopml.png)

I am trying to align the error message for the Green and Blue field so it looks like the Yellow.

Here's how I created the two columns:

```css
form.form div.form-col-1 { float: left !important; clear: left !important; width: 49% !important; padding-left: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important; padding-bottom:10px; }
form.form div.form-col-2 { float: right !important; clear: right !important; width: 49% !important; padding-right: 0 !important; padding-left: 0 !important; margin-right: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important; padding-bottom:10px;}
```

Here's my error codes:

```css
form.form p.error.no-label { position:relative; top:0; background: transparent; color: red; padding: -5px; margin-top:2px; z-index:1000; font-size: 14px; font-family:'Klavika Rg', 'Klavika', Arial !important; font-weight: 400; }
```

FYI, this is the form from Account Engagement, formerly Pardot.
Happy to hear any suggestions and possible solutions. TIA!

Comment: please add your html code (if would be great to attach a sandbox)